# If I have the following SQL database, how can I get this information?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Trying to learn TSQL once and for all :P

I'd like to select a list of Productos ordered by Category.

**EDIT:**

Here is the query I created with your help, but it's still not showing exactly what I'd like:

```
select p.Nombre as Nombre, c.Nombre as Categoria FROM Producto as p
inner join Subcategoria as s ON p.IDSubcategoria = s.ID
inner join Categoria as c on s.IDCategoria = c.ID
group by p.Nombre, c.Nombre
order by p.Nombre
```

Result:

[image]

So it would show:

```
Product Name, Product count, that has category X
Product Name, Product count, that has category X
Product Name, Product count, that has category X
Product Name, Product count, that has category X
```

Comment: Looks like each product belongs to a single category. How do you track the numbers of each product? Do you simply need to display the category each product belongs to? If it is the number of products _per_ category, how are you supposed to select a single product?

Comment: Other tables, for now I'd just like to list how many product the company has for sale in each category. Each subcategory belongs to a single category, so that would help me out I assume. Thanks for the help.

Comment: OK, how are you supposed to select a single product name per category if you have multiple products on a category? And where do you store the number of items per product?

Comment: A record in Product is like a catalog of products. It's not meant to handle counts or prices or anything. It's just a catalog.

Answer (score 1):

out the back of my head, and assuming that the number of records in Proveedor is the Count:

```
SELECT p.Nombre as Name, COUNT(pr.*), c.Nombre as Category FROM Producto as p
INNER JOIN Subcategoria as s ON p.IDSubcategoria = s.ID
INNER JOIN Categoria as c on s.IDCategoria = c.ID
INNER JOIN Proveedor as pr ON p.IDProveedor = pr.ID
GROUP BY p.Nombre, c.Nombre
ORDER BY p.Nombre
```

Please don't shoot me if it has a few errors.

Comment: So where do you get the Count from?